# indexedDB doesn't keep DB, store or values when puppeteer closed Chrome

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, indexeddb

I am still new to Node.js/JavaScript.  I am trying to use indexedDB from Node.js with puppeteer.  I was able to add values in indexedDB as shown in the below png image.   Since transanction.oncomplete occurred after adding values in store, I believe that the DB/store/values were saved on disk.  But when I closed the Chrome puppeteer opened and open the same html page by puppeteer or by myself, the DB was gone.  I get the html page from a server I am renting. I am running Node.js +puppeteer on my PC at home.

I am getting the html from the same url address and running the puppeteer on the same PC.  So I think that this is within the security boundary of indexedDB.

Can anyone help me by tell me what I am missing to keep the indexedDB after the puppeteer closes the Chrome window?

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
         headless: false,
         defaultViewport: null,
         devtools: true,
         args: ['--start-maximized']
    });
   const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
  // await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 1200});
   await page.goto('https://ichiri.biz/test/auth/a/');

   page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
   await page.evaluate(() => {
     
    var db;
    var item = [{
        name: 'banana',
        price: '$1.99',
        description: 'It is a purple banana!',
        created: new Date().getTime()
      },{
        name: 'apple',
        price: '$2.99',
        description: 'It is a red apple!',
        created: new Date().getTime()
      }
    ];
    var openReq = indexedDB.open('test_db', 1);
    
    openReq.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
      var db = e.target.result;
      console.log('running onupgradeneeded');
      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('store')) {
        console.log('no store');
        var storeOS = db.createObjectStore('store',
          {keyPath: 'name'});
      }
    };
    openReq.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log('running onsuccess');
      db = e.target.result;
      addItem(item);
      //getItem();
    };
    openReq.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log('onerror!');
      console.dir(e);
    };
    
    function addItem(item) {
      var tx = db.transaction(['store'], 'readwrite');
      var store = tx.objectStore('store');
      var req;
      item.forEach(function(data){
        req = store.add(data);
      })
      req.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e.target.error.name);
      };
      req.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log('Woot! Did it', e);
      };
      tx.oncomplete = function(e){
        console.log("tx completed", e);
      }
    }

    function getItem() {
      var tx = db.transaction(['store'], 'readonly');
      var store = tx.objectStore('store');
      var req = store.getAll();
      req.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e.target.error.name);
      };
      req.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      };
    }
   });
```

http://ichiri.biz/test/auth/a/my_indexeddb_20201127.png

Comment: I guess that indexedDB doesn't hold data when accessed from Node.js, which is outside of browser, for security reason.   When I tried indexedDB in browser as JavaScript, it worked perfectly.  I just wanted to use some durable and secure datastorage to keep sessionID or UUID in client side.  I guess that I have to use websocket between python and JavaScript in client side to store values in indexedDB for IoT application.   It would have been nice if I could save data in indexedDB directly from Node.js or Python in client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puppeteer doesn't store any data between runs, by default everything is deleted after the script exits — in order to guarantee reproducible test results it is necessary to start each script from a clean slate.

However it is possible to keep any data generated during a puppeteer script run, just set `userDataDir` path when [launching puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerdefaultargsoptions):

```
await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: '/path/to/some/folder',
});
```

Comment: Hi Vaviloff, thank you very much for your help.    After I used your userDataDir in launch, now I am able to change, add values in the table of indexedDB from Node.js.  This is great!    I found that there are two different storages for indexedDB when I set the userDataDir.

1. My Local Dir   --- Only Puppeteer/node.js can use when data was added by puppeteer.
2. In Browser  --- Data JavaScript added can be changed by Puppeteer and keeps the change.  But JavaScript doesn't see the data which was added by puppeteer.

But this works for me.   Thank you very much again.